# extract a vector of pixels from a frame using OpenCV?

Tags: android, image-processing, opencv, pixel

I'am actually working in a project on android in which I want to extract some specific pixel values (according to a condition, using the threshold method , I have set some pixels to a certain values and all the others to zero) I want to extract all these values different from zero in a vector. I will use this vector of the chosen pixels to do some operation ( the mean value for exemple ) , Is there a method in OpenCV that can help me doing this ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know such function but actually it's not hard to implement it (c++):

```
//'in' should be CV_8UC3
vector<int>& getNonZero(const Mat& in)
{
    //get size of result vector
    //this is all non-zero pixels:
    int count = countNonZero(in);
    vector<int>& result(count);
    int k = 0;

    for (int r = 0; r < in.rows; ++r)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < in.cols; ++c)
        {
          if (in.at<int>(r, c))
          {
              result[k++] = in.at<int>(r, c);
          }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

And also many OpenCV functions have `InputArray mask` parameter so use it! For example:

[`void meanStdDev(InputArray src, OutputArray mean, OutputArray stddev, InputArray mask=noArray())`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#void%20meanStdDev%28InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20mean,%20OutputArray%20stddev,%20InputArray%20mask%29)

Comment: Your solution seems to work but, manipulating the elements one by one will be very slow in my opinion especially when doing it in real time !! For each frame takin from the camera , doing all these loops will certainly slow the processing and maybe the application will crash !!

Comment: For the other method ; I don't really see how to use the InputArray mask to eliminate the 0 values for example from the calculation of the mean !!

Comment: @3arbouch be quiet, bro - why screaming? Have you tried to google usage of these methods instead of screaming on me? The `InputArray` should be just binary mask (`Mat`) if pixels. For example, if pixel in mask at position `(i,j)` equals 0 than in original image this pixel won't be taken for mean calculation. Did you read the description of function??!!

Comment: I'am not screaming at you at all bro :) it just that the problem pisses me off ! Sorry for that ;) Yes I read the documentation, and don't really see how to do it :( Do you mean that if I just put an Array containing just ones, this will ignore the 0 values when calculating the mean ?

Comment: Just read some examples of usage and you will get it. I don't want to rewrite existing examples here.

Comment: @3arbouch yes. they will ignore the places of the source image, where the corresponding mask image has a 0 pixel value. @Astor I was thinking of the `meanStdDev()` example when first saw this question too

Comment: @AruniRC , I just use the method :  Scalar mean(InputArray src, InputArray mask=noArray()) and put a as a mask : Mat.ones(image.size,CV_8U) ; where the image is the image from which I will calculate the mean value of the pixels different from zeros ! unfortunately , this does not ignore the zeros values :( I do not really see how this can works, In another way, after reading the documentation of who the mask is used, I think that I should put a mask with a 3*3 size with the value one in the center and zeros around but this generate an Error!Please tell me if I have something wrong.Thank you :D

Comment: Thank you guys! i get it , I just use my image (Mat gray for example ) as a mask to calculate the mean of this image without taking the 0 values !For instance, we have an image in a Mat ( Mat gray )to calculate the mean of the pixels without taking the 0 values , I use this same mat as a mask :  Core.mean(gray,gray) .